# Count fequency of a list in range 0-10, and outputing this frequency including 0

Tags: python-3.x, frequency

I have a program that will ask the user for a number as many times as they want so long as it is within the range 0-10.

I want to then output the frequency of each input for that range including if the number wasn't entered by the user at all. So by default it would be 0.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for.

Input:

```
1
5
1
2
5
8
9
5
5
```

Wanted Output:

```
0 - 0
1 - 2
2 - 0
3 - 0
4 - 0
5 - 4
6 - 0
7 - 0
8 - 1
9 - 1
10 - 0
```

So far I have a list that stores the users inputs, and a dictionary with keys going from 0-10, with each having a value of 0. I've found code that gives the frequency of the users input but it's unordered and only for the numbers inputed. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I'd like to add, I'm hoping to do this without importing any modules.

Comment: What have you tried?  "without importing any modules" typically means "because the teach said so" and we don't do your homework for you.  but if you post your honest attempt we can guide you where you have problems.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've tried mainly using a for loop, "for 'num' (the variable I used for my numbers) in 'nums' my list which stores the numbers, to somehow correlate that to my dictionary, but im kinda just lost. I'd be happy to share my code so far just let me know how, im pretty knew to this forum.

Comment: @MarkTolonen And about the teacher thing your half right, I took an introduction course to coding a year back but dropped it because it was a little stressful. However I find coding really fun when I get to do it at my own leisure, so I've decided retry most of the assignments I've had in the past. And it's kinda habit to use the least amount of modules possible because of that course, it's also so that I can have  better understanding how things work as I'm sure the course intended, but no worries tho if you're not up to help! Sorry for noti spam!

Comment: I'm fine to help, but show your coding attempt.  Edit the question with your best attempt and point out what isn't working for you.  You won't learn as well if someone just writes the answer for you.